# How do you create a new contact group with the People API in Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-people-api

I'm having trouble navigating the docs for this, so I thought I would ask here? How do you create a new (empty) contact group using the People API with Google Apps Script? I'm trying to find a contact group by name and create it if it doesn't exist.

This is what I have now:

```js
function findContactGroupId(groupName) {
  allContactGroups = People.ContactGroups.list();
  Logger.log(allContactGroups);
  for (i=0; i<allContactGroups.contactGroups.length; i++){
    Logger.log(allContactGroups.contactGroups[i]);
    if (allContactGroups.contactGroups[i].name == groupName) {
      return allContactGroups.contactGroups[i].resourceName
    }
  }
  return null
}

function somefunc() {
  contactGroupName = "foo";
  contactGroupResourceName = findContactGroupId(contactGroupName);
  Logger.log("got resource id: %s", contactGroupResourceName);
  contactGroup = People.ContactGroups.get(contactGroupResourceName);
  if (!contactGroup) {
    contactGroup = People.ContactGroups.create(contactGroupName);
    Logger.log("Contact Group %s created", contactGroup);
  }
}
```

I'm using the API incorrectly, but can't figure out the right invokation. I seems like I have to make a `CreateContactGroupRequest`, but I'm not sure how to do that. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter is the `ContactGroups: create` request body ([reference](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/contactGroups/create#request-body)):

```js
function createTestGroup() {
  const r = People.ContactGroups.create({
    contactGroup: {
      name: "test"
    }
  })

  console.log(JSON.stringify(r))
}
```

You can also add the `readGroupFields` for more granular control about what you get returned.

### References

- [`ContactGroups: create` (People API reference)](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/contactGroups/create)